# AMcharts stockchart 2 timeseries on y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am making an AMcharts stockchart with markers on it.  The way I have done the markers is by taking the value of the price series only if a condition is met.  Therefore the data has 4 columns:

1. Date
2. SPY price (SP500 etf)
3. Daily RSI Stance 1 (1,0 boolean value)
4. Signal (If Daily RSI Stance 1 = 1, SPY price, else blank)

CSV with data found here:

http://quantresearch.club/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/testing/RSI1dip.csv

The problem is that even though the data is perfectly aligned it does not show that way on the amcharts chart, which has me completely stumped.  The markers ie. "4. Signal" show up under the "2. SPY price" timeseries.  As shown here:

[image]

and finally for the code:

This first part is contained in the larger code below and it is what makes both timeseries appear.

```
 "panels": [ {    
      "stockGraphs": [ {
        "id": "g1",
        "title": "SPY Price",
        "valueField": "spy",
        //"type": "line",
        "lineColor": "#39fe90",
        "useDataSetColors": false
     },{
        "id": "g2",
        "title": "Signal",
        "valueField": "Signal",
        "bulletSize": 10,
        "bullet": "round",
        //"bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "lineColor": "#551A8B",
        "useDataSetColors": false
AmCharts.loadFile(  "http://quantresearch.club/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/testing/RSI1dip.csv", {}, function( response ) {
  var csvData = AmCharts.parseCSV( response, {
    "useColumnNames": true
  });
  //var csvDataLength = csvData.length;
  chartData = [];
  guideData = [];
  //var a = 0;
  //var b = 0;
  //var c;
  var lastdate;
  var firstdate;
  $.each(csvData, function(i,k){
      if(k.Date != undefined) {
        chartData.push( {
          "Date": k.Date,
          "SPY": k.SPY,
          "Signal": k.Signal
        })
      }
  });
  //console.log(guideData);
     chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "stock",
    "theme": "light",
    "categoryAxesSettings": {
      "labelRotation" : 30, 
      "minPeriod": "DD",
      "axisAlpha" : 1,
      "gridAlpha": 0,
      //"dateFormats" : "MMM-YYYY",
    },
    "legend": {
      "useGraphSettings": true
    },
    "dataSets": [ {
      "fieldMappings": [{
        "fromField": "SPY",
        "toField": "spy"
      },
      {
        "fromField": "Signal",
        "toField": "Signal"
      }],

      "dataProvider": chartData,
      "categoryField": "Date",}],

   //Where the chart gets populated

    "panels": [ {    
      "stockGraphs": [ {
        "id": "g1",
        "title": "SPY Price",
        "valueField": "spy",
        //"type": "line",
        "lineColor": "#39fe90",
        "useDataSetColors": false
     },{
        "id": "g2",
        "title": "Signal",
        "valueField": "Signal",
        "bulletSize": 10,
        "bullet": "round",
        //"bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "lineColor": "#551A8B",
        "useDataSetColors": false
      }],

    "stockLegend": {
        //"periodValueTextComparing": "[[percents.value.close]]%",
        "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]",
        //"labelText" : "SPY",
        "combineLegend": true,
        "markerType" : "line"
      }
    }, ],

    "chartScrollbarSettings": {
      "graph": "g1",
      "usePeriod": "DD",
      "position": "bottom",
      "gridAlpha": 0
    },
    "chartCursorSettings": {
      "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
      "fullWidth": true,
      "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
      "valueLineEnabled": true,
      "valueLineAlpha": 0.5
    },

    "periodSelector": {
      "inputFieldsEnabled" : true,
      "position": "top",
      "periods": [ {
          "period": "YYYY",
          "count": 2,
          "label": "2Y"
        }, {
          "period": "YYYY",
          "count": 5,
          "label": "5Y"
        },
        {
          "period": "YYYY",
          "count": 10,
          "label": "10Y"
        },
        {
          "period": "MAX",
          "label": "MAX",
          "selected": true,
        }
      ]
    },
    "valueAxesSettings": {
      "gridColor": "#555",
      "gridAlpha": 0,
      //"axisAlpha" : 1,
      "inside": false,
      "position": "right",
      "showLastLabel": true
    },

    "panelsSettings": {
      "usePrefixes": false,
      "marginRight" : 20,
      "marginBottom" : 10,
      "marginLeft" : 20,
      "marginTop" : 10
    },

    "export": {
      "enabled": true,
      "position": "top-left"
    }
  } );
  /*chart.addListener("init", function(event) { 
    console.log(event);
  });*/

});
```

If anyone has any ideas about this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the stock chart's [data grouping functionality](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/). The chart groups data to improve performance when there a lot of points visible, which impacts how the line is drawn as it is using points derived from its data grouping algorithm. By default it's using the `"Close"` value in the grouping to plot your points and changing the [`periodValue`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#periodValue) in your SPY graph will change the appearance. Since your Signal data set has much fewer points in comparison, the chart simply plots out the raw values for that graph, which do not match up to your grouped SPY graph's values, regardless of which `periodValue` you use.

Your only option to make the values from both graphs line up correctly is to disable data grouping by setting [`maxSeries`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#maxSeries) to 0 in your `categoryAxesSettings`. This will impact performance if you have a lot of points.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a9c3cc1634ec3e467eede5c4603cbc26?editors=0010) of your chart with `maxSeries` set to 0.